# How to deal with Keyrror on API calls

Tags: python

How can I best handle KeyError on my python script ?

My script is calling an API which give some JSON information.

The JSON information, give assets (Servers) information and sometimes some information are not provided by the API.
For example, if the hostname is not known, the API will not give any hostname key into the json answer.

I tried :

```
try:
   address = asset['addresses'][0]['ip']
   hostname = asset['hostNames'][0]['name']
   os = asset['os']
except KeyError as e:
   hostname = ""
```

But if there is another KeyError I'll only modify the hostname variable.

How can I handle all KeyError exceptions ? Do I have to do this, or is there a better way to do this ?

```
try:
    address = asset['addresses'][0]['ip']
except KeyError as e:
    address = ""
try:
    hostname = asset['hostNames'][0]['name']
except KeyError as e:
    hostname = ""
try:
    os = asset['os']
except KeyError as e:
    os = ""
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`dict.get` to get a value or fall back to a default if the key is not found](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get).

```
address = asset['addresses'][0].get("ip", "")
hostname = asset['addresses'][0].get("name", "")
os = asset.get("os", "")
```

If there are no  `addresses` at all or the index 0 isn't find, it will still crash.

To alleviate that, you can guard with e.g.

```
addresses = asset.get('addresses', [])  # list of addresses, or an empty list
first_address = (addresses[0] if addresses else {})  # first address or an empty dict

address = first_address.get("ip", "")
hostname = first_address.get("name", "")
os = asset.get("os", "")
```